# Cannot open Sound Settings in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, xfce, ubuntu-studio

A couple of days ago I removed/changed something (I don't remember what it was) but since then I cannot access the Sound Settings. I have tried to installing/re-installing alsamixer, pulseaudio, and other things but none of them brought back the settings. I could only access them via the speaker icon in the panel, because in the system settings did never appear nothing related to them.

I can change the audio interface I am using via the alsamixer command in the terminal, but there are still some settings I cannot change with it. Also, the volume up/down and mute of my keyboard have stopped working.

I have been researching all kinds of solutions but none of them worked and I don't know what can I do more. Can someone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: if you 'removed/changed something' using the terminal; you should be able to view your command `history` to see what it was you did (and thus undo it).  the next place to look would likely be your software logs `/var/log/apt/..` (though this assumes change/remove was apt* command & not a .conf change)

Comment: I removed all files in .config/pulse but I am not sure if that was the cause. Isn't it any way to install it as it came from the time I installed the OS?

Comment: use your `history` to see what files you stuffed up, then say it was `/etc/blah.conf` you could do a `dpkg -S /etc/blah.conf` to find out that package created the file.  use a command like `dpkg -L blah` to list files contained in package 'ntp' (this isn't needed, but helps you to learn etc). then use `dpkg-reconfigure blah` to restore that package back to 'defaults'.  yes there are ways to restore system back to defaults  (eg. `dpkg -l` can list installed debs & `dpkg-reconfigure` will reset them, but that's a messy re-install anyway).  I prefer to fix the mess myself as I learn & improve :)